# How to consume API which is created in nodejs-express-oracledb

Tags: node.js, oracle, oracle-jet, node-oracledb

I would want to consume `GET/PUT/POST/DELETE` API’s through a web page (HTML) which would be integrated on the Oracle JET.
The webpage will have one input free text option, where the user can type in to update the record.
i.e. If I click on one record on the JET dashboard, the API `‘GET /alluser/:FIRST_NAME` – Read the profile of an user’ will be called, 
it will display the detailed record with one text box as free text, 
once the user enters text and hits submit, `‘PUT /process_post` – Update the profile of an user’ API will be called, which will update the record.

Here is my script

```
var express = require('express');
var oracledb = require('oracledb');
var app = express();
var dbConfig = require('./dbconfig.js');

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var port = 3000;
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // Use body parser to parse JSON body
oracledb.outFormat = oracledb.OBJECT;
// Get a non-pooled connection
function run() {
 oracledb.createPool({
      user          : dbConfig.user,
    password      : dbConfig.password,
    connectString : dbConfig.connectString
    },
    function(err) {
      if (err)
        console.error("createPool() error: " + err.message);
      else
        var server = app.listen(port,
          function () {
            console.log('Server is listening on port ' + server.address().port);                
          });
    });
}
 function doGetConnection(res, cb) {
  oracledb.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
    if (err) {
      res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      res.status(500).send(JSON.stringify({
        status: 500,
        message: "Error getting DB connection",
        detailed_message: err.message

      }));
    } else {
      cb(err, connection);
      console.log("  Connection is connected");
    }
  });
}


app.post('/process_post', function (req, res) {
console.log("contenttype"+req.get('Content-Type'))      
  doGetConnection(res, function(err, connection) {
    if (err)
      return;
    connection.execute(
      "INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE(FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME) VALUES (:FIRST_NAME,:LAST_NAME)",
    [(req.body.FIRST_NAME),(req.body.LAST_NAME) ],

      { autoCommit: true,
      outFormat:oracledb.OBJECT
      },
       console.log("check2"),
      function (err) {
      console.log("check3");
        if (err) {
        console.log("check4");
          res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
          res.status(400).send(JSON.stringify({
            status: 400,
            message: "Input Error",
            detailed_message: err.message
          }));
        } else {
          // Successfully created the resource
          res.status(201).set('Location', '/process_post/' + req.body.FIRST_NAME).end();

        }
        doRelease(connection, "POST /process_post");
      });
  });
});

app.get('/alluser', function (req, res) {
  doGetConnection(res, function(err, connection) {
    if (err)
      return;
    connection.execute(
      "SELECT * from employees",
      function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
          res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
          res.status(500).send(JSON.stringify({
            status: 500,
            message: "Error getting the farmer's profile",
            detailed_message: err.message
          }));
        } else {
          res.contentType('application/json').status(200);
          res.send(JSON.stringify(result.rows));
        }
        doRelease(connection, "GET /bananas");
      });
  });
});
app.get('/alluser/:FIRST_NAME', function (req, res) {
  doGetConnection(res, function(err, connection) {
    if (err)
      return;
    connection.execute(
      "SELECT * from employees  WHERE first_name = :f",
      { f: req.params.FIRST_NAME },
      function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
          res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
          res.status(500).send(JSON.stringify({
            status: 500,
            message: "Error getting the farmer's profile",
            detailed_message: err.message
          }));
        } else if (result.rows.length < 1) {
          res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
          res.status(404).send(JSON.stringify({
            status: 404,
            message: "FIRST_NAME doesn't exist",
            detailed_message: ""
          }));
        } else {
          res.contentType('application/json');
          res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(result.rows));
        }
        doRelease(connection, "GET /user/" + req.params.FIRST_NAME);
      });
  });
});

function doRelease(connection, message) {
  connection.close(
    function(err) {
      if (err)
        console.error(err);
      else
        console.log(message + " : Connection released");
    });
}
run();
```

Thank you.

Comment: You make http calls from web page Javascript using either the XMLHttpRequest API or the Fetch API.  Those are your two choices.

Comment: thanks for your response,Can you send me some useful link to do that.

Comment: Well, I gave you the names of the two APIs.  In the future, you should be capable of googling them to find thousands of examples yourself.  The web is full of examples.  Here are two relevant MDN pages [Using XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) and [Using Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).  Fetch is the newer API and a bit easier to use, but can't quite do everything that XMLHttpRequest can.

Comment: Hi @Karthick was my answer helpful?

Comment: Also, see this post for tips on how to better organize your API code: https://jsao.io/2018/03/creating-a-rest-api-with-node-js-and-oracle-database/

Comment: HI Ray, thanks for your response.it is very much helpful to me.thank you..

Comment: Hi Dan,Thanks for your response,i will refer to it.

Comment: Hi Karthick. You're welcome. In that case please consider accepting and/or upvoting my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Oracle JET can help you make API calls.

Here's an example from their Cookbook: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jetCookbook.html?component=crud&demo=model

Have a look at the documentation for [Collection](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jsdocs/oj.Collection.html#get) and [Model](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jsdocs/oj.Model.html).

It's a lot to read if you're getting into it for the first time, so I'll give a quick example for a GET all:

```
var dataModel = oj.Model.extend({urlRoot: 'example.com'});
var modelInstance = new dataModel();

var CollectionConfig = {
   model: modelInstance,
   url: 'example.com'
};
var dataCollection = oj.Collection.extend(CollectionConfig);
var collectionInstance = new dataCollection();
collectionInstance.fetch({
                success: function (collection, response, options) {
                    console.log(response);
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                }
            });
```